# How to register a local Julia package in a local registry?

Tags: package, julia

I have a Julia package in my home directory under the name `Foo`. Foo is a directory with `Project.toml` file that describes the package dependences, name, etc. I want to be able to use this package from another folder in a particular manner as follows.

1. Build the package `Foo`
2. Register `Foo` in a local Julia repository
3. Run `Pkg.add("Foo")` from anywhere on the system, such as script.jl which would have the following:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("Foo")
using Foo

# Now use Foo
Foo.bar()
```

Here is what I've tried so far.

- Navigate to `Baz` directory where I want to run `Baz/script.jl`
- Use `repl`, hit `]` and run `dev --local PATH_TO_FOO`
- From `repl`, run `using Foo`
- `Foo` is now accessible in the current `repl` session (or script)
- Summary: I have managed to import a package `Foo` in another directory `Baz`.

Basically, I want to be able to write a `script.jl` that can make use of the local registry instead of this `dev --local .` method.

Comment: This is a great question. I have the same one. Looking forward to the answer.

Comment: The answer is really involved. You need to create a a registry (as a local git repo, with a special structure I think?) then add it to the local list of registries (easier on 1.1+), then add your package to it (which is actually really complex but there is a script for it on an issue in Pkg.  I don't think i'll have time to answer this properly.

Comment: Bits: create private registry https://discourse.julialang.org/t/creating-a-registry/12094/6. Add to private registry https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/Registrator.jl/issues/197. Adding a registery https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/registries/

Comment: If someone wants to glue the above two comments and extract the key content from the links it would make a great answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume that this is for personal use and you are not a system administrator for a large group.

Maintaining a registry is hard work. I would avoid creating a registry if at all possible. If your goal is to make the use of scripts less painful, a lighter solution exists: shared environments.

A **shared environment** is a regular environment, created in a canonical location. This means that `Pkg` will be able to locate it by name: you do not have to specify an explicit path.

To set up a shared environment:

- give it a name: `Pkg.activate("ScriptEnvironment"; shared=true)`
- populate it: `Pkg.add(Pkg.PackageSpec(; path="/path/to/Foo"))` (depending on your use case, you can also use `Pkg.develop`, add registered packages, etc)
- that's all!

Now all your scripts can use the shared environment:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.activate("ScriptEnvironment"; shared=true)
using Foo
```

If other sets of scripts require different sets of packages, repeat the procedure with a different shared name. `Pkg` environments are really cheap so feel free to make liberal use of this approach.

---

Note: I would discourage beginning scripts with `Pkg.add("Foo")` because this carries the risk of inadvertently polluting the active environment.

Comment: Even lighter would be to install it to the global (v1.2 etc) environment

Comment: What does shared do?

Comment: `shared` creates the environment in a canonical location. try `Pkg.activate("v1.2"; shared=true)`.

Comment: Oh neat. Add that to answer?

Comment: @DavidVarela My goal is to build a repository of local tools that cannot go out in the wild (proprietary IP) and I want a simple way to use the Julia's package manager in a local environment.

Comment: Would this approach not require a shared file system across all machine where the packages are to be deployed?

Answer (score 2):

There are some instructions on registry creation and maintenance at https://github.com/HolyLab/HolyLabRegistry.